Joystick & Jump Button are hidden by game scene. Priority doesn't work
I'm adding a joystick and other HUD buttons to the game with the highest priority but they are always hidden by the game scene once it is loaded. I ensured them to be added after adding the scene, but it never works.
Jump Button
Joystick
Level
I was trying to add a joystick component and a jump button to my game and it did work fine couple weeks back or something but now it seems that priority doesn't seem to affect the z-index of the components. On the mobile, the layout makes the buttons hidden, although still playable but still I don't know what seems to be the issue here.

From the code you've shared, it seems you are creating a new World and CameraComponent for each level. But it also seems that you are adding the joystick to the default FlameGame.camera. If that is the case, adding the joystick to the correct camera should work.
Also, it would be much nice if you share the code directly in the question, instead of posting images. With the current images, one can only guess which class that code snippet is part of .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78137709/789545
